# Text highlight color with Gtk

Tags: ruby, gtk, ruby-gnome2

I am developing a desktop application with Gtk. When designing a dialog that has a textbox, I noticed that the text highlight color was not matching the UI design requirements. The color I see by default is shade of blue but I'd like it to be a shade of orange. See the attached image for clarity.[image: Image Link]

I have tried things like setting the background/base but it doesn't work.

```
entry.modify_bg(Gtk::STATE_SELECTED,Gdk::Color.parse("orange"))
```

Any idea how I can get it to work the way I want? For what it's worth, I'm programming in Ruby with Gtk as the front end framework.

Comment: I have a slight guess (from my past memory) that your OS setting might be having priority over your setting in the Gtk app. Is the color that you currently see the color that you see in other apps on your environment?

Comment: Best way is to utilize CSS, Gtk3 supports it. To know which class text-highlight inherits from, you can use Gtk inspector. Its like your Chrome console.